# adding a generated number to another

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to make a blackjack game. so i want to make it add the first generated number to the one that is generated when hit is typed into the interface.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CTA {
    public static void main(String[] ARGS) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        Scanner hs = new Scanner();
        int n = rand.nextInt();
        int o = rand1.nextInt();
        if ((n < 1) || (n > 21)) {
            System.out.println(rand.nextInt(25));
            System.out.println("Value is out of range 1-3");
            System.out.println("Please try again");
            if (hs == hit) {}
            if (hs == stay) {}
        }
        if ((o < 1) || (o > 21)) {
            System.out.println(rand1.nextInt(25));
            System.out.println("Value is out of range 1-3");
            System.out.println("Please try again");
            if (hs == hit) {
                System.out.println(rand1.nextInt(25));
            }
            if (hs == stay) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the actual question?

Comment: Where are `hit` and `stay` declared, and what will comparing two instances of `Scanner` for equality accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look into how to use a Scanner. For example,

```
if (hs == hit) {
```

is testing if the scanner hs is equal to the variable hit ... which is never declared. You shouldn't be testing equality with a scanner directly (this will fail), as well as either replace hit with "hit" (include the quotes) or declare `String hit = "hit";` somewhere up above.

As for the scanner, pay close attention to `scanner.next();` in this link. It should help:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to add two numbers together, then in your hit function, you will have to sum the two numbers, you will also need a thrid int for hand score.

```
int handTotal;

if (hs == hit) 
{
   handTotal = o + n;
}
```